# Converting point shapefile with N points to N layers with one point each using Global Mapper

Tags: shapefile, global-mapper

I have a point shapefile layer that contains 50 points. I want to create 50 layers with these points. Meaning every point ends up in its own layer.

How can I do this using Global Mapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy as long as each point has a distinct attribute (it can be the name). In such case you just right click on the layer and select the option "Split Into Separate Layers based on Description/Attribute value".

If they don't have a distinct attribute you have to create one. There are multiple ways to do that.  It could be to load a terrain layer and apply the elevations to the points (then you can split the points into layers based on their elevation). Or you can export your points to CSV, open in Open Office or Excel and just add a new column with a sequential number ID 1,2,3,....,50.  Then load into Global Mapper and split by ID.